# Why are stack values so far apart in Rust?

Tags: rust

When I run

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: i32 = 0;
    println!("{:p}", &x);
    let y: i32 = 1;
    println!("{:p}", &y);
}
```

in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=68c50c327480fd301e130637a07316a4), the  values printed are, in decimal, 88 apart. My expectation would be that they would be 4 or 8 (bytes) apart. Why is it so large?

Comment: Is it the same when you declare your variables at the beginning of the function?

Comment: No, in that case the difference is 4. So why would it be so large in the case above?

Comment: It is also worth noting that in "release" mode the difference goes down to 4, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `println!` macro will use stack variables too. If you swap the order of your statements around (in Rust Playground debug at least), the two pointers are 4 bytes apart:

```
fn main() {
    let x: i32 = 0;
    let y: i32 = 1;
    println!("{:p}", &x); // 0x7ffe0b865db0
    println!("{:p}", &y); // 0x7ffe0b865db4
}
```

There are no guarantees about how the stack is used, and it's very likely to be different with an optimised binary.

Answer (score 0):

After a small [test](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU6GaSwEIclJLFCqsFDKNjRRsFQys4WKVMDFDiFhBUWZeSU6eooZStVVBrZKOglqFJi6ZSqBM7f//AA) and some [reading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) (`println` is a macro) i would assume that the macro creates additional code that causes the addresses of your variables to be more than the expected 4-8 bytes appart.